# DataBricks (10.2) - Data Source Name Missing from Feature Store Table Description After Create

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

After I create a Feature Store table using described syntax:

```
fs.create_table(
    name="FeatureStore.TableName",
    primary_keys=["feaKey1", "feaKey2"],
    schema=sttSchemaName
    df=DataFrameName_df,  
    description="Table Description."
)
```

the table appears in Feature Store GUI as proscribed, but the original data-source name is empty.  I find no mention of this on DataBricks FAQs/help or here on SO.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an un-addressed issue in DataBricks Feature Store as of this writing - the problem is related to passing both a schema and a dataframe to the call.  Although this syntax should work, it fails to register the input data source name with the Feature Store.  The solution is to call create without the schema (perhaps altering the schema after the fact, if necessary).